# python, beautifulsoup tag seems nonetype

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loz5X.png)

In this code, type(tag) returns "Nonetype", but I have to see bs4.element.tag instead of nonetype.
Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: your image is incomplete as well as your question. Soup will give none type if there is no data at that location you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

In line 5, `bclass` should be `b class`.